# AsyncTask refresh imageView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I use an AsyncTask class for execute a task and show an ImageView.
But I execute this task every 10 seconds, for this I call the same task in :
`onPostExecute()` method.

It's work but the imageView refresh after 10 seconds, why ?

This is my code :

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myView);
        imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        SVG svg;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(mySVG);
            svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(is);
            Drawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture());
            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        } catch (SVGParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        imageView.refreshDrawableState();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) < 10000) {
        }

        AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void> t = new Task(rootView).execute();
    }
```

This code refresh the imageView after 10 seconds, but I would refreshed immediately, wait 10 seconds and execute another Task...

Comment: I think it's not a good idea, coz when your put a loop command in your code and never break it, your will lock your code in a specific thread. be careful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, you're using an `AsyncTask` and then "eat CPU" in the `onPostExecute()`

```
while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) < 10000) {
}
```

Don't do this.

Use a `Handler` / `Runnable` combination.

Here's an example:

In your `Activity` you do:

```
private Handler timerHandler;
private Runnable timerRunnable;

// ...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    timerHandler = new Handler();
    timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do your refresh here
            timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 10000);
        }
    };
    timerHandler.post(timerRunnable);
}
```